# D8 Use Mongo for custom entity storage

Tags: entities, database

Thanks to Drupal 8 new field storage architecture, we can read *everywhere* that we can use other database than Sql, for example MongoDb, to store fields data.

I have a custom entity with some custom fields which will have to store a lot of (small) *rows* in database. I want to use the Drupal Entity, as recommended, (fieldable, etc) to store my data, instead of using a custom table like I did before with Drupal 7.

I ask myself if it's possible to use another database storage than Sql ; like MongoDb for my specific entity. I read some example for Drupal 7 but I'm not sure how to do with Drupal 8. There is [Mongodb](https://www.drupal.org/project/mongodb) module, about more or less ported to Drupal 8 but it's not very clear.

Thanks for your comments and your help.